# ASP.NET Core disable timepicker for datetime-local

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

So I'm dealing with an issue I have a standard core app. With the model which has following:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime StartOfSit { get; set; }
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime EndOfSit { get; set; }
```

My view looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="StartOfSit" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="StartOfSit" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="StartOfSit" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EndOfSit" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EndOfSit" class="form-control" asp-format="{0:d/M/yyyy}"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="EndOfSit" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Yet even though I tried multiple ways I cannot disable time picker (blue square) from the input field. 
[image: Error]

EDIT:
Managed to solve it with `Type = "date"` but now I cannot change month to be displayed as a number not an actual name, tried with : `{0:dd-mm-yyyy}` and didn't work.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

try with that

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartOfSit { get; set; }
```